# ANTLR error is always "no viable alternative at input"

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to show `ANTLR` errors to users by implementing `BaseErrorListener`

```
public class CustomErrorListener :BaseErrorListener
{
        public override void SyntaxError(IRecognizer recognizer, IToken offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, string msg, RecognitionException e)
        {
            List<string> stack = ((Parser)recognizer).GetRuleInvocationStack().ToList();
            stack.Reverse();
            Debug.WriteLine("rule stack: " + stack);
            Debug.WriteLine("line " + line + ":" + charPositionInLine + " at " + offendingSymbol + ": " + msg);
        }
}
```

But I always get the `no viable alternative at input` error

with the following grammar

```
prog : expr+ EOF;

expr : COLUMN LESSTHAN DECIMAL BIGGERTHAN DECIMAL  # range
     | COLUMN BIGGERTHAN DECIMAL LESSTHAN DECIMAL  # inversedRange
     | COLUMN operator DECIMAL                     # simple
     ;

operator : LESSTHAN | BIGGERTHAN | EQUALS;

COLUMN     : 'all'? ('column' | 'otherColumn')
DECIMAL    : [0-9]+ '.'? [0-9]*;
LESSTHAN   : '<' | '<=';
BIGGERTHAN : '>' | '>=';
EQUALS     : '=';
WS         : [ \r\n\t] -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

If I type `column >` 
I would expect an error like `decimal is missing` instead of `no viable alternative at input column >`

Is it a problem with my grammar?

**EDIT**

I'm asking this because with my hello world grammar, I'm able to get other errors like `token recognition error` if I type `2 + e`. I would expect the same with my grammar if I type `column > d`

```
/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

prog: expr+ ;

expr : expr op=('*'|'/') expr   # MulDiv
     | expr op=('+'|'-') expr   # AddSub
     | INT                      # int
     | '(' expr ')'             # parens
     ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */
INT : [0-9]+;
MUL : '*';
DIV : '/';
ADD : '+';
SUB : '-';
WS
    :   (' ' | '\r' | '\n') -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a problem with my grammar?

No. The problem, if any, is in understanding what Antlr is doing at the point of the error. The rule stack will show the sequence of successfully invoked rules. In this case, there will only be `prog` as none of the `expr` alts will match completely (or likely nothing as not even `prog` completed). All that Antlr can say with certainty is that, beginning with the input `column >`, it can find no alt of any rule that will match.

The best way to debug this kind of error is to use the rule stack to locate the point of the error in the token stream and dump the tokens that follow. Here the dumped tokens would be `<COLUMN> <BIGGERTHAN> <EOF>`, making the nature of the error clear.

Comment: Then I don't understand why I don't get an error like `token recognition error` if I type column > d. No matter what I type, I always get the no viable error

Comment: Because there is no `token recognition error` -- the lexer ran to completion with no errors, so all tokens recognized & generated.  It is the parser that failed to find a viable alt to match the token sequence corresponding to the input text that it is reporting. If you wish to change or add to the text being generated, add the ErrorListener to the Parser, do not print `msg`, analyze the token stream at the point of the error, and print what you believe is significant. If this does not answer your question, please explain why you think you should be getting something different and from where.

Comment: Thank you. I know you right but see my edit. What's the difference between the 2 grammars. With my hello world, I get other errors.

Comment: @Marc What happens if you remove the rule alternative of: COLUMN operator DECIMAL? What error do you get? Maybe its doing that because the grammar you have is ambiguous as to which rule to follow on an error.

Comment: @Har Thank you. You are right. By removing that rule, I managed to get errors like missing decimal. This is what I want. Is there a way to remove the ambiguity in my grammar?

Comment: I am not sure if this would satisfy your needs: exprP: COLUMN operator DECIMAL extension?;
extension: BIGGERTHAN DECIMAL #range
         | LESSTHAN DECIMAL   #inverseRange;

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem with that is that someone could type column = 2 > 3